# A more portable blender game engine?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

I was curious about blender game engine and it's portability. It seems that for the most part blender is pretty portable, the main difficulty is moving around the python parts of blender to other platforms.

I am coming at this from a game developer standpoint. If I write a game in blender with Logic Bricks and assets, and if I want to pack that up and deliver it to the marketplace, it doesn't seem feasible. All the stuff I've read seem to have shown a stall in mobile games built in Blender. If blender didn't require the python parts, at least in the run time it could easily be packaged up as a C/C++ project which can be built for almost any platform out there.

If it is possible to build a version of Blender to work without python with no noticeable differences, wouldn't it significantly improve the portability of the Game Engine? Does anything like this currently exist, and if not, has it been attempted before or could it be attempted now?

Comment: I made a longer reply below but talking about mobile platforms for blender games.

Answer (score 2):

Python is an integral part of blender's design, python is used to define the user interface of blender and some operators that perform tasks are also in python. Removing python would really disable blender from functioning.

Using only the game engine it may be possible to run it without python as you won't be using any of the pre-defined UI, only object rendering through opengl, provided you don't use any python scripts in your game logic.

Blender's use of python isn't likely to be a factor in mobile distribution. While desktop usage of the game engine is as broad as blender's availability, the main thing that you will find preventing blender's game engine being used for mobile games would be the limited support of openGL ES, which is used on mobile devices. There has been a couple of attempts at starting this but I'm not certain of the current state of progress.

I believe you will most likely find that blender's GPL licensing forcing developers to also release their games as GPL and possibly still being in conflict with the Apple Store TOS, that it would be the main factor in it's non-use for commercial and/or mobile games.